# Weird behavior when launching powershell through different ways

Tags: windows-10, powershell-v5.1

I have a Powershell script assigned to the context menu and it has been running fine. Recently, after I've reset my win10 system and then manually reconfigured my whole system Powershell begins to behave weirdly. The script won't be run correctly anymore, after a lot of researches I find that the problem is caused by the `Set-Clipboard` cmdlet which being the PCSX version when launching through the context menu where it being the original version if I launch powershell manually. How comes it happen? My script has `Set-Clipboard` with `-value` parameter which is not present in PCSX version and it causes an error.

[image: PCSX version]
[image: Original version]

Comment: Inspect the commandlines being used for launching both instances. We can't do that for you since we are not the ones sitting in front of your computer. You'll find the context menu commandline in the registry.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Alright, the context menu is made by myself in order to load a script when copying paths to WSL bash terminal. The command line is `powershell.exe -window hidden -command .'"G:\...path to the script...\Copy as Linux Path.ps1"' '%v'`